# hg template data DOS command line syntax

Tags: windows, command-line, mercurial

Using Mercurial 3.9 on Windows 7.

If I enter at the DOS command line:

`hg log filename --template {date(date)}\n`

I get reasonable output like:

```
Fri May 27 16:36:56 2016 +0000
Fri May 27 16:07:56 2016 +0000
Fri May 27 16:07:00 2016 +0000
Fri May 20 19:22:12 2016 +0000
Fri Apr 29 13:09:16 2016 +0000
Tue Apr 26 17:06:52 2016 +0000
```

But if I try to use the date format code like:

`hg log filename --template {date(date, "%%m")}\n`

I get an error:

`abort: cannot follow file not in parent revision: "path/to/file/%%m)}/n"`

where `path/to/file` is the path within the repository to `filename`.

I think the `%%` is needed to escape the `%` in DOS, but anyway it causes the same error if I leave out the escaping. In fact, if causes the same error even if I simplify it more:

`hg log filename --template {date(date, "m")}`

Same error again.

**How can I correctly enter this template on the command line?** This error is really confounding.

Note that putting it in a style file DOES work, like:

`changeset = '{date(date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")}\n'`

which is the entire format string I'd actually like to use.

Comment: Plain `hg log -T "{date(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')}\n"` works in my console

Comment: @Lazy Badger It must be the quotation marks which caused the problem - yours does work. You should add that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

`hg log filename --template "{date(date, '%m')}\n"`

The problem is that the template argument breaks on the space and the rest seems to be used as path: `filename + "%%m")}\n` (very strange - my hg version shows a different error)

The double quotes are for the CMD and the single quotes for hg (python).